# Convert SQl query to MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

```
SELECT * 
FROM data WHERE (object,TCH_Traffic) IN 
( SELECT object, MAX(TCH_Traffic)
  FROM data
  GROUP BY object
)
```

Can this above query be modified to run with MS Access database.
I am getting error to "revise the select statement of " prompt as attached in MS access 2010 db.

[image]

Comment: Try: `SELECT d.* FROM  data d JOIN (SELECT object, MAX(TCH_Traffic) AS TCH_Traffic
  FROM data
  GROUP BY object) AS s ON d.object=s.object AND d.TCH_Traffic=s.TCH_Traffic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data
WHERE TCH_Traffic = (SELECT MAX(d2.TCH_Traffic)
                     FROM data as d2
                     WHERE d2.object = data.object
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Access' default Jet/ACE SQL Engine can process a subquery in a `WHERE` condition using `IN` clause. However, subquery must return one column value. Consider the following adjustment:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data WHERE (object) IN 
   ( SELECT object
     FROM data
     GROUP BY object
     HAVING TCH_Traffic = MAX(TCH_Traffic)
   );
```

However, you can simply use a derived table with `INNER JOIN` and avoid `WHERE` clause subquery. Also, same derived table query can be saved as  a stored query object in MS Access and explicitly referenced in join clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data     
INNER JOIN
   ( SELECT object, MAX(TCH_Traffic) As maxTraffic
     FROM data
     GROUP BY object
   ) As dT    
ON data.object = dT.object
AND data.TCH_Traffic = dt.maxTraffic
```